I can't install wxPython on Windows 11 ARM64
I tried to install via python -m pip install wxPython on my Windows 11 ARM64
Bug got errors (error log will be at the bottom, and it's the same as if I was installing through build.py build)
Then I tried to unzip wxPython from tar.gz and install it via ...build.py build, and then I realized what the problem was. This stupid thing is trying to use x64 components and x64 cl.exe instead of ARM64 components and ARM64 cl.exe (While my Python is ARM64) and that's why the compiling breaks down. I tried to replace the file cl.exe on the specified path, to ARM64 cl.exe, but got an error:
C:\Users\MaxRM\Downloads\wxPython-4.2.2>"C:\Users\MaxRM\Downloads\3.9.7\tools\python.exe" -u C:\Users\MaxRM\Downloads\wxPython-4.2.2\build.py build

Will build using: "C:\Users\MaxRM\Downloads\3.9.7\tools\python.exe"

3.9.7 (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:06:44) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (ARM64)]

Python's architecture is 64bit

cfg.VERSION: 4.2.2

Running command: build

Running command: build_wx

   CL.exe:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe

wxWidgets build options: ['--wxpython', '--unicode']

Updating wx/msw/setup.h

setting build options...

nmake.exe -f makefile.vc UNICODE=1 OFFICIAL_BUILD=1 COMPILER_VERSION=140 SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=0 USE_OPENGL=1 USE_GDIPLUS=1 BUILD=release

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.41.34120.0

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        if exist ..\..\lib\vc140_x64_dll\wxtiff.lib del ..\..\lib\vc140_x64_dll\wxtiff.lib

        link /LIB /NOLOGO /OUT:..\..\lib\vc140_x64_dll\wxtiff.lib @C:\Users\MaxRM\AppData\Local\Temp\nmEC01.tmp

vc140_x64_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_open.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'ARM64' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'link /LIB /NOLOGO /OUT:..\..\lib\vc140_x64_dll\wxtiff.lib @C:\Users\MaxRM\AppData\Local\Temp\nmEC01.tmp' : return code '0x458'

Stop.

Error building

ERROR: failed building wxWidgets

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\MaxRM\Downloads\wxPython-4.2.2\build.py", line 1588, in cmd_build_wx

    wxbuild.main(wxDir(), build_options)

  File "C:\Users\MaxRM\Downloads\wxPython-4.2.2\buildtools\build_wxwidgets.py", line 503, in main

    exitIfError(wxBuilder.build(dir=buildDir, options=args), "Error building")

  File "C:\Users\MaxRM\Downloads\wxPython-4.2.2\buildtools\build_wxwidgets.py", line 72, in exitIfError

    raise builder.BuildError(msg)

buildtools.builder.BuildError: Error building

Finished command: build_wx (0m2.168s)

Finished command: build (0m2.172s)

Main part in this log is: fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'ARM64' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' so this stupid thing thinks that target arch is x64, but it must be ARM64.
And here error log if not replace cl.exe:
C:\Windows\System32>"C:\Users\MaxRM\Downloads\3.9.7\tools\python.exe" -u C:\Users\MaxRM\Downloads\wxPython-4.2.2\build.py build

Will build using: "C:\Users\MaxRM\Downloads\3.9.7\tools\python.exe"

3.9.7 (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:06:44) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (ARM64)]

Python's architecture is 64bit

cfg.VERSION: 4.2.2

Running command: build

Running command: build_wx

   CL.exe:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe

wxWidgets build options: ['--wxpython', '--unicode']

Updating wx/msw/setup.h

setting build options...

nmake.exe -f makefile.vc UNICODE=1 OFFICIAL_BUILD=1 COMPILER_VERSION=140 SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=0 USE_OPENGL=1 USE_GDIPLUS=1 BUILD=release

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.41.34120.0

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl /c /nologo /TC /Fovc140_x64_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_jpeg.obj /MD /DWIN32 /Zi  /Fd..\..\lib\vc140_x64_dll\wxtiff.pdb   /O2 /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1  /D_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS=1 /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1  /D__NO_VC_CRTDBG__  /DNDEBUG  /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /I..\..\src\zlib /I..\..\src\jpeg  /I..\..\src\tiff\libtiff /D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS   ..\..\src\tiff\libtiff\tif_jpeg.c

tif_jpeg.c

        cl /c /nologo /TC /Fovc140_x64_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_jpeg_12.obj /MD /DWIN32 /Zi  /Fd..\..\lib\vc140_x64_dll\wxtiff.pdb   /O2 /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1  /D_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS=1 /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1  /D__NO_VC_CRTDBG__  /DNDEBUG  /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /I..\..\src\zlib /I..\..\src\jpeg  /I..\..\src\tiff\libtiff /D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS   ..\..\src\tiff\libtiff\tif_jpeg_12.c

tif_jpeg_12.c

        cl /c /nologo /TC /Fovc140_x64_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_luv.obj /MD /DWIN32 /Zi  /Fd..\..\lib\vc140_x64_dll\wxtiff.pdb   /O2 /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1  /D_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS=1 /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1  /D__NO_VC_CRTDBG__  /DNDEBUG  /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /I..\..\src\zlib /I..\..\src\jpeg  /I..\..\src\tiff\libtiff /D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS   ..\..\src\tiff\libtiff\tif_luv.c

tif_luv.c

        cl /c /nologo /TC /Fovc140_x64_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_lzma.obj /MD /DWIN32 /Zi  /Fd..\..\lib\vc140_x64_dll\wxtiff.pdb   /O2 /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1  /D_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS=1 /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1  /D__NO_VC_CRTDBG__  /DNDEBUG  /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /I..\..\src\zlib /I..\..\src\jpeg  /I..\..\src\tiff\libtiff /D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS   ..\..\src\tiff\libtiff\tif_lzma.c

tif_lzma.c

        cl /c /nologo /TC /Fovc140_x64_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_lzw.obj /MD /DWIN32 /Zi  /Fd..\..\lib\vc140_x64_dll\wxtiff.pdb   /O2 /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1  /D_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS=1 /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1  /D__NO_VC_CRTDBG__  /DNDEBUG  /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /I..\..\src\zlib /I..\..\src\jpeg  /I..\..\src\tiff\libtiff /D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS   ..\..\src\tiff\libtiff\tif_lzw.c

tif_lzw.c

        cl /c /nologo /TC /Fovc140_x64_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_next.obj /MD /DWIN32 /Zi  /Fd..\..\lib\vc140_x64_dll\wxtiff.pdb   /O2 /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1  /D_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS=1 /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1  /D__NO_VC_CRTDBG__  /DNDEBUG  /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /I..\..\src\zlib /I..\..\src\jpeg  /I..\..\src\tiff\libtiff /D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS   ..\..\src\tiff\libtiff\tif_next.c

tif_next.c

        cl /c /nologo /TC /Fovc140_x64_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_ojpeg.obj /MD /DWIN32 /Zi  /Fd..\..\lib\vc140_x64_dll\wxtiff.pdb   /O2 /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1  /D_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS=1 /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1  /D__NO_VC_CRTDBG__  /DNDEBUG  /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /I..\..\src\zlib /I..\..\src\jpeg  /I..\..\src\tiff\libtiff /D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS   ..\..\src\tiff\libtiff\tif_ojpeg.c

tif_ojpeg.c

There are many more similar lines of errors as above, so there is no point in duplicating them, especially since there are restrictions on the limit of characters here and I will not be able to insert everything.
So I would like to understand how to get Python to use the correct ARM64 compiler and ARM64 components instead of x64.
